# slick 3.3.2 not joining when explicitly writing a join query

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying to get two tables joined with slick 3.3.2 and play 2.7.x, but i'm having a hard time understanding why my codes doesn't do what i want it to.

I have two tables: `Foo` and `Bar`, both with string that i need to join on a string column, lets call it `fooBar`

```
val innerJoin = for {
  (f, b) <- Foo join Bar on (_.fooBar === _.fooBar)
} yield (f, b)
db.run(innerJoin.result)
```

Docs say this is the way to do it: http://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.2/queries.html#applicative-joins

But the query slick generated when debugging, doesn't actually use a join, it simply selects the properties from the two tables, like so: (simplified) `select * from Foo, Bar where (x2.fooBar = x3.fooBar)` clause

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Slick has generated a join there, but it's in a form known as an "implicit join" (in SQL).

It's a syntax difference, and you can check with your database documentation to see if the query optimiser will treat them the same.

As a rule I would not worry about the surface SQL text Slick generates, unless there's a performance issues which you can identify by profiling the query plan in your database.

Comment: There are loads of those (performance issues), as soon as you start writing anything else than simple selects from a single table, hence why i want slick to not behave like a madman. I've decided to just use plain old SQL instead, as it's much simpler to write, read, understand and much faster in general. With some performance tests, there's hundreds of milliseconds to gain with replacing even simple slick-queries, that basically just does `select * from table where x = x`, with plain sql of the exact same SQL statement that slick generates under the hood. Thanks for your answer though.